# Проиграть анимацию с помощью скрипта и animator?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public Animator anim;
public void Load()
{

    anim.PlayInFixedTime("planet animation");


    //Application.LoadLevel(1);
}
```

Но возникает ошибка

> Controller 'Sphere': Transition '' in state 'planet animation' uses parameter '' which does not exist in controller.

или же

> Animator does not have an AnimatorController

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При включеном аниматоре у вас и так сразу запустится эта анимация о.о зачем вам использовать вызов этого метода?

Comment: В ошибках же указано- вы или используете недопустимые параметры, или на обьекте вообще нет аним контроллера

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте какие параметры нужны при переходе в анимацию 'planet animation' http://prntscr.com/iye3vk
2. У вас в аниматоре не задан аним. контроллер http://prntscr.com/iye4eu

Comment: Параметры у меня никакие не заданы. А насчет того что у меня не задан аним. контроллер - хотел уточнить - у меня есть пустой GameObject - на котором висит скрипт и там public поле в которое я и передаю animator для скрипта. А сам этот GameObject - я передаю для события OnClick - кнопки. На самом объекте - на сфере  - "Планета Земля" - сам аним. контроллер я не добавлял - иначе анимация проигрывается автоматически.